# nodejs hosting from my laptop

Tags: node.js, express, web, hosting

I have a website that uses nodejs with express. The website is working fine on my localhost.
I am not able to find a way to host the website from my laptop i.e. allowing external users to connect to it remotely.
I wanted to check if this is possible. I am using windows 7.

I used to do the same job with php however, I used wamp server. Is there a similar way for nodejs?

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

> I used to do the same job with php however, I used wamp server. Is there a similar way for nodejs?

It's identical.  Assuming Node.js is listening on the correct interfaces, there is no reason why you can't forward a port in from your router to your server on your laptop.

Comment: Thank you. What do you mean by listening on the correct interfaces?

Comment: @PrologProgrammer Your computer has one or more network interfaces.  There is the loopback interface with the IP address of 127.0.0.1, and there will be some other network adapter interface which connects to your home router, and it will have another IP address, say 192.168.100.1.  Your application can bind to a specific address, or 0.0.0.0 which means to bind to all addresses.  If you were to bind to 127.0.0.1, then traffic on other interfaces won't make it to your application.

Answer (score 1):

I use ngrok. You go to [ngrok.com](http://ngrok.com) and download the client. Then you can do a quick and easy command from your shell and tell ngrok to open the port you are running your Node site on. Something like...

`ngrok http 3000`

Comment: I recommend you pay a little something (they let you pay whatever you want) to ngrok since they've created such a nice tool. that way you can get subdomains so instead of having a random url like dOIudofd.ngrok.io, you get something like whateveriwant.ngrok.io and it stays the same. Pretty cool.